# rPi & ASICMiner Block Limit?

Tags: asic

So I am thinking about getting back into bitcoin and I recently discovered the ASICMiner Block Erupter. And I see that just about everyone has them running on a USB3 hub. Lets say that I ran 8 of these Block Erupters on a single hub that was connected to the rPi. Now I know that the hub is USB3 and the rPi has only a USB2 connection. Would that be okay? And would the rPi be able to handle or process the bitcoin mining application? Or would I need to use a little better PC to handle it?

I chose the rPi because it consumes low power itself, and I can have it run 24/7 than a PC.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both Debian and Arch Linux on an rPi to run Butterfly Labs mining equipment; the rPi was able to handle up to 9 SC Singles with CPU to spare using recent versions of both bfgminer and cgminer. So I suspect that it would not have any difficulty driving eight Block Erupters.

Be sure to take some care in choosing your [USB hub](http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs) (it will need to be powered) and you may find [MinePeon](http://minepeon.com/index.php/Main_Page) to be a useful package for getting things set up.